# Laravel- como enviar datos por put/patch al método update en el controlador desde un formulario

Tags: laravel

recien volvi a retomar laravel y después de un rato practicando lo que sabía me tope con un problema que segun yo no tenía nada de malo hasta que lo hice y fue cuando desde el formulario en action queria hacer usar del método update por medio de la router como en el ejemplo:

```
<form id="formUpdateCalzado" method="PUT" action="{!! route('calzado.update', $idproducto) !!}" >
```

Por cierto al inspeccionar el codigo y mirar lo que me generaba elroute calzado.update y con el dato idproducto si generaba bien la ruta:

```
action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/calzado/1"
```

Esta es la parte que uso para obtener todos los metodos:

```
Route::resource('calzado', CalzadoController::class);
```

Y el metodo del controlador es el siguiente:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {   //intente imprimir el dato de entrada
        return $id;
       // tambien intente usar el echo $id;
         
    }
```

Bueno esto es lo unico que tengo, entonces cuando hacia submit al formulario de actualizar datos del producto y desde el método update del controller quería imprimir los datos en pantalla no visualiza nada. Pero no entiendo porque y al igual cuando hacía una consulta eloquemet donde recibía el idproducto tampoco me funcionaba, sabrán que estoy haciendo mal o porque no me esta funcionando el update? pareciera que no esta entrando al método porque no imprime los valores. También agregue en mi formulario el @csrf pero tampoco funciona. Lo único que quiero es que funcione e imprima los datos pero no lo hace. Me ayudan por favor. Por cierto al hacer uso del calzado.edit si me funciona el route y el método edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la documentacion de laravel dan un ejemplo muy claro que debes usar

`@method('PUT')` en tu formulario te pongo un ejemplo con el codigo que otorgas

```
<form id="formUpdateCalzado" method="POST" action="{{ route('calzado.update', $idproducto) }}" >
@csrf // o {{ csrf_token() }}
@method('PUT')
```

con esto le dices a laravel que el metodo por el que se enviara este formulario es de tipo PUT

Comment: Loooool, revise cuidadosamente la doc y no lo encontre, pero siempre hice formularios y nunca supe de @method('PUT') . Muchisimas gracias bro

Comment: te dejo la refencia de la documentacion, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#form-method-spoofing, puedes ponerlos con inputs ocultos o de esta manera que te mostre (es lo mismo pero mas barato)

Comment: Gracias Amigo. Juro que habia leido bien la documentación y no lo vi, se me paso por algo y era algo tan sencillo

Comment: No te precoupes para eso estan estos foros, para aprender y asi sea minima la pregunta de enviar un metodo PUT en algun momento tambien a muchos nos falla, pero lo importante es no dejar de aprender